# Handle button click event of button list inside UIScrollView Monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl on my View in my iPhone app. I populate this Scrollview with a list of 10 buttons. The buttons all populate correctly an I can scroll through them perfectly. My question is: How do I wire up a click event to each of those buttons? Each button will perform essentially the same task (Play a sound) however the sound will be different for each of these buttons. The buttons are created programatically by the following method:

```
    private void CreatePanels()
    {
        scrollView.Scrolled += ScrollViewScrolled;

        int count = 10;
        RectangleF scrollFrame = scrollView.Frame;
        scrollFrame.Width = scrollFrame.Width * count;
        scrollView.ContentSize = scrollFrame.Size;

        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            
            float h = 150.0f;
            //float w = 50.0f;
            float padding = 10.0f;
            int n = 25;
            
            var button = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            button.SetTitle (i.ToString (), UIControlState.Normal);
            UIImage img = new UIImage("Images/btntest.png");
            button.SetImage(img, UIControlState.Normal);
            button.Frame = new RectangleF (
                        (padding + 40) * (i + 1) + (i * (View.Frame.Width - 100))   , 
                        padding,                        
                        View.Frame.Width - 100,         
                        h);

            RectangleF frame = scrollView.Frame;
            PointF location = new PointF();
            location.X = frame.Width * i;

            frame.Location = location;
            button.Frame = frame;

            scrollView.AddSubview(button);
        }

        pageControl.Pages = count;
    }
    
    private void ScrollViewScrolled (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double page = Math.Floor(((scrollView.ContentOffset.X - scrollView.Frame.Width) / 2) / scrollView.Frame.Width) + 1;

        pageControl.CurrentPage = (int)page;
    }
```

The CreatePanels() method is called within the ViewDidLoad() method which populates the UIScrollView.

How can I link a click event to each of these buttons? I have searched the internet a lot but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about wiring up an anonymous method to each click event in the for loop?

`button.TouchUpInside += (s, e) => 
{
   //play i.mp3

};`

I'm not sure how to actually play a sound file but you could have your sound files named as i.* since that is what your buttons are named.

Comment: Thanks for this. It solved my problem. I have to set the buttons tag property to i though to know which button was clicked. Thanks for your help. Thumbs up!